# Audit ManyToMany Relationships using Hibernate Envers

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I'm using Hibernate Envers in order to audit my entities. But I have a problem. I want to audit an Entity that have a ManyToMany relationship. I found that exists an @AuditJoinTable but I don't have idea how it works. Can someone giveme an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Auditing many-to-many relations should work without any additional configuration, provided that both sides of the relation are audited.

As to `@AuditJoinTable`, the annotation is used to specify a custom table name of the join table. See:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/AuditJoinTable.html

The default name is `[Referencing entity name]_[Referenced entity name]_AUD`. The annotation doesn't have to be used, if the default table name is fine.