# Auditing Info for JoinTable using @ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I cannot get the AuditInfo columns to be created when using @ManyToMany relations. Both @Entity objects extend AbstractAuditable and the correct columns are created when using create-drop.  The AutitInfo columns do not show in the auto created join table.

I see this post regarding Hibernate Audit info, and it says it should be autmatically created. [Audit ManyToMany Relationships using Hibernate Envers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030588/audit-manytomany-relationships-using-hibernate-envers)
Should that work with Spring JPA since Hibernate is the provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem ended up being that I didn't include an `orm.xml` file included that declared an `AuditingEntityListener`.  I had thought it would be enough to include the `@EnableJpaAuditing` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data auditing only captures the reference to latest modifying and creating user as well as the creation and modification date. It does *not* keep revisions of entities around. If you need the latter, the tool of choice is [Hibernate Envers](http://envers.jboss.org/) which we have a custom [Spring Data extension](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers) for.

Comment: I'm not trying to keep revision history. I'm just trying to get audit info working for a ManyToMany join table.  I do not have an Entity object for the join table since it is inferred through the ManyToMany annotation.  Therefore I cannot set the Auditing annotations or extend AbstractAuditable.

Comment: Hi @oliver-gierke did you see my comment?